# Append-only comments field from SP List not displaying in Infopath form

Tags: infopath, form, forms-library, append-changes

I am trying to get a data connection set up in InfoPath to display the comments history in a multi-line text field with "Append Changes to Existing Text" option enabled. The field comes from a SharePoint Form Library which is what the form submits to (no problems there).

I was able to get a normal multi-line text field to display properly in the form with the same data connection, but when I turn on "Append Changes to Existing Text" nothing shows in the text area on the form.

I have read that this should be possible from sources such as [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/sharepoint2010customization/thread/1391097e-0bf3-4e8e-aa72-667eda63057f) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-BZ/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/b2bf6dfd-8a10-4a26-9f79-6eb3739ff7ef) but have not been able to get it working myself. Can anyone provide a little more detail on setting this up? I am trying to avoid workarounds that involve recreating the functionality with custom columns but I will do that if there is no other option.

My environment is SharePoint Enterprise 2010 with InfoPath 2010. Considering I'm using a Form Library, could the problem be that this only works with normal lists?